# Amazon EMR --wait-for-steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I'm writing a bash script that runs an aws emr command (aws emr version 1.5.2).

How do I tell my script to wait until the emr job finishes before proceeding? The `--wait-for-steps` option is depreciated now.

via [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) I got this, but it just seems like the wrong approach:

```
STEP_STATUS_STATE=$(aws emr list-steps --cluster-id ${CLUSTER_ID} | jq '.Steps[0].Status.State' | tr -d '"')
while [[ ${STEP_STATUS_STATE} == PENDING ]] || [[ ${STEP_STATUS_STATE} == RUNNING ]]; do
    STEP_STATUS_STATE=$(aws emr list-steps --cluster-id ${CLUSTER_ID} | jq '.Steps[0].Status.State' | tr -d '"')
    echo $(date) ${STEP_STATUS_STATE}
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: That's not good practice for a persistent EMR cluster. You should put you proceeding commands be called by the cluster public DNS master node. Something like "ask for DNS value every 10 minutes, once the DNS is not null, get it".

Answer (score 2):

I use AWS java api to wait till job is finished like below. Hope this helps

```
 public static final List<JobFlowExecutionState> DONE_STATES = Arrays
        .asList(new JobFlowExecutionState[] {
                JobFlowExecutionState.COMPLETED,
                JobFlowExecutionState.FAILED,
                JobFlowExecutionState.TERMINATED });
```

...

```
  public static boolean isDone(String value) {
    JobFlowExecutionState state = JobFlowExecutionState.fromValue(value);
    return Constants.DONE_STATES.contains(state);
}

   .
   .
  STATUS_LOOP: while (true) {
        DescribeJobFlowsRequest desc = new DescribeJobFlowsRequest(
                Arrays.asList(new String[] { result.getJobFlowId() }));
        DescribeJobFlowsResult descResult = emr.describeJobFlows(desc);
        for (JobFlowDetail detail : descResult.getJobFlows()) {
            String state = detail.getExecutionStatusDetail().getState();
            if (isDone(state)) {
                logger.info("Job " + state + ": " + detail.toString());

                if(loadToDailyDB && state.equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED"))
                {

                    //Do something
                }
                if(!state.equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED"))
                {

                }

                break STATUS_LOOP;
            } else if (!lastState.equals(state)) {
                lastState = state;
                logger.info("Job " + state + " at "
                        + new Date().toString());
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(75000);
```

Comment: Interesting - but I was hoping I could do this via a simple command line argument like the previous version of aws allowed...

Answer (score 2):

Try using AWS emr wait step-complete option.
Have a reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/wait/step-complete.html).